# Cat into fifo not running through bash

Tags: shell, fifo

I want to script these few lines

```
mkfifo my.fifo
cat >my.fifo &
cat my.fifo | nc remotehost.tld 10000
```

But the line

```
cat >my.fifo &
```

When i run it manually it works, but not through bash shell. 
what could be the reason for it?

Comment: what do you mean "when you run it through bash shell"? What shell are you using when you run it manually? Your question (as phrased) doesn't make sense...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) Create the first file

```
#!/bin/bash

mkfifo my.fifo
trap 'rm -f my.fifo' EXIT

cat  <my.fifo &
cat >my.fifo;
nc localhost 2345
```

2) From another terminal

```
cat >my.fifo
```

Comment: Added `trap`  to remove the created file `my.fifo` once there pipe is closed.

Comment: why the 2) thing though ?